# Not able to fully access $scope variables inside stripe callback?

Tags: angularjs, stripe-payments

I'm running into strange issues trying to integrate stripe in an angular project. I'm running the stripe methods inside my controller and I want to update various scope values from the callback. I believe there is some scope issue I'm not understanding. I can console log my scope variables inside the callback, update them and console log again to see the new values. However if I try to log the variables again outside of the callback I get the old values and then new values are not making it into my view. I've also tried moving my $scope primitives to a $scope object to no avail. Here's an example.

```
app.controller('checkoutCtrl', function ($scope) {

    // default values
    $scope.receipt = {};
    $scope.paymentSuccess = false;
    $scope.saveCardForFuture = true;

    Stripe.card.createToken($scope.card, function (status, res) {

        $scope.receipt = res.data;
        $scope.paymentSuccess = true;

        if ($scope.saveCardForFuture === true) {
            // save card token
        }

        // tests cases
        console.log($scope.saveCard)       //logs undefined
        console.log($scope.receipt)        //logs the response data
        console.log($scope.paymentSuccess) //logs true 
    });

    // timeout long enough to wait for stripe response
    $timeout(function() {
        console.log($scope.receipt);       //logs {}
        console.log($scope.paymentSuccess) //logs false
    }, 1000);

});
```

Note: Stripe is not passed as a controller dependency, I just include it globally from my html index page. I haven't yet found a way to include it as an injectable dependency but there must be a better way.

Comment: Since the callback runs outside Angular's lifecycle, start by adding a `$scope.$apply()` in the end to make changes visible to Angular. Have no idea how Stripe works, so I cannot help any furhter.

Comment: As far as dependency injection is concerned, you can add the `Stripe` global object as a value into the IOC (`angular.module('myApp').value('Stripe', Stripe);`), and then request it via dependency injection. That gives you the option to provide setup a mock `Stripe` object for testing and have your controller code annotated with `"use strict";`. It does not mean that `Stripe` is no longer a global object.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You left the angularjs world in the stripe callback. Enclose the callback bock with $scope.$apply(fn);

Some good reading: http://jimhoskins.com/2012/12/17/angularjs-and-apply.html

```
app.controller('checkoutCtrl', function ($scope) {

    // default values
    $scope.receipt = {};
    $scope.paymentSuccess = false;
    $scope.saveCardForFuture = true;

    Stripe.card.createToken($scope.card, function (status, res) {
        $scope.$apply(function () {
            $scope.receipt = res.data;
            $scope.paymentSuccess = true;

            if ($scope.saveCardForFuture === true) {
                // save card token
            }

            // tests cases
            console.log($scope.saveCard)       //logs undefined
            console.log($scope.receipt)        //logs the response data
            console.log($scope.paymentSuccess) //logs true 
        });
    });

    // timeout long enough to wait for stripe response
    $timeout(function() {
        console.log($scope.receipt);       //logs {}
        console.log($scope.paymentSuccess) //logs false
    }, 1000);

});
```

Comment: Thank you this worked and $scope.$apply is definitely something I'm happy to be aware of. That was a great article you linked.